# Mounting ExFAT on Linux

Tags: samba, raspberry-pi, fstab, external-hdd

I've been trying to set up my Raspberry Pi B+ as a HTPC that also shares a USB HDD over Samba and AFP. The latter is working just fine, and the Samba share seemed to be working too for a moment. However, whenever I try to connect to the Pi now (no modifications AFAIK) it shows me the folders with small stop icons. The following links unfortunately didn't offer me any help.

- [Mount exFAT file system as user without specifying /dev/sdX1 in /etc/fstab](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/111492/mount-exfat-file-system-as-user-without-specifying-dev-sdx1-in-etc-fstab)
- [Cannot mount exFAT even though I installed exfat-fuse](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/150626/cannot-mount-exfat-even-though-i-installed-exfat-fuse)

**initialization**

```
sudo mkdir /mnt/Data
sudo chown osmc:osmc /mnt/Data
sudo chmod -R 777 /mnt/Data
sudo apt-get install exfat-fuse exfat-utils
```

**mount**

```
/dev/sdb2 on /mnt/Backups type hfsplus (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,umask=22,uid=1000,gid=0,nls=utf8)
/dev/sdb1 on /media/EFI type vfat (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,uid=1000,gid=1000,fmask=0111,dmask=0000,allow_utime=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=ascii,shortname=mixed,showexec,utf8,errors=remount-ro,uhelper=udisks)
/dev/sdb3 on /mnt/Data type fuseblk (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other,blksize=4096)
```

**cat /proc/filesystems | grep fuse**

```
        fuseblk
nodev   fuse
nodev   fusectl
```

**blkid**

```
/dev/sdb3: LABEL="Data" UUID="5563-32E4" TYPE="exfat" PARTLABEL="Data" PARTUUID="91a3c291-cfcf-4b17-ba57-538c29c3f951"
```

**fdisk -l**

```
Disk /dev/sdb: 2,7 TiB, 3000592977920 bytes, 732566645 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 4096 = 4096 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: C5BDA252-07EB-4C54-B1EF-35AC14D16381

Device         Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sdb1          6     76805     76800   300M EFI System
/dev/sdb2      76806 244217437 244140632 931,3G Apple HFS/HFS+
/dev/sdb3  244250368 732566527 488316160   1,8T Microsoft basic data
```

**cat /etc/fstab**

```
/dev/mmcblk0p1  /boot    vfat     defaults,noatime    0   0
/dev/mmcblk0p2  /    ext4      defaults,noatime    0   0

UUID=eae6464d-bd99-39f5-91a9-7d41b61356d4 /mnt/Backups hfsplus rw,force,exec,auto,users 0 3
UUID=5563-32E4 /mnt/Data exfat rw,force,exec,auto,user,umask=0 0 0
```

I've tried the following:

- changing "exfat" in /etc/fstab to "fuse-exfat", "exfat-fuse", "fuseblk". All without luck.
- manually mounting using:

  - sudo mount /dev/sdb3 /mnt/Data
  - sudo mount -t exfat /dev/sdb3 /mnt/Data
  - sudo mount -t exfat-fuse /dev/sdb3 /mnt/Data
  - sudo mount.exfat /dev/sdb3 /mnt/Data
  - sudo mount.exfat-fuse /dev/sdb3 /mnt/Data

**/etc/samba/smb.conf**

```
[global]
   workgroup = HOME
   server string = %h server
   dns proxy = no

   log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
   max log size = 1000
   syslog = 0
   panic action = /usr/share/samba/panic-action %d

   security = user
   encrypt passwords = true
   passdb backend = tdbsam
   obey pam restrictions = yes
   unix password sync = yes

   passwd program = /usr/bin/passwd %u
   passwd chat = *Enter\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *Retype\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *password\supdated\ssuccessfully* .
   pam password change = yes
   map to guest = bad user

   usershare allow guests = no

[homes]
   comment = OSMC
#  browseable = no
   path = /home/osmc/
   valid users = @users, root, osmc ###this seemed necessary according to a guide
   force group = users
   create mask = 0777
   directory mask = 0777
   read only = no
```

The funny thing is, on every single one of these commands. The /mnt/Data privileges change to (drwxr-xr-x, root:root) and go back to normal when I unmount the volume. I'm guessing OS X won't let me browse into any directory as it is owned by root and I'm connecting as osmc. What seems to be going wrong here?

Regards,
Rowan Kaag

Comment: I suggest you to keep away from potentially dangerous proprietary file systems.

Comment: @neverMind9, That's a rather useless suggestion unless you tell us a replacement file system that is compatible with Windows, Linux, and Mac, and suitable for drives over 4GB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed that by default, OSMC also shares external HDD's over Samba. On connecting to the Raspberry via Samba, I get the following options:

- osmc
- homes (not relevant in this case)
- Data (ExFat partition on HDD)

When connecting to `osmc`, from my understanding, it serves me `/home/osmc` which has symlinked folders that I put there, e.g.: `/home/osmc/Movies -> /mnt/Data/Movies`

This results in the behaviour I mentioned before, giving me red warning circles on the folders. However when connecting directly to 'Data', everything works fine. I figured this would suit me and couldn't be bothered waiting for an answer here as I'm really impatient.